# Can Visual Studio Unit Tests be "Run as Admin" on Vista?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, windows-vista

We have some unit tests which work with performance counters (specifically creating new categories) and on XP/2003 they work fine but on Vista/7 they fail with a SecurityException ("Requested registry access is not allowed").  I tried checking the "Run as administrator" box on the properties for `VSTestHost.exe`, but that causes *all* tests to fail immediately marked with with an Error and no message.

Does anyone have any suggestions for running Visual Studio Unit Tests (ideally just *these* tests) with administrative privileges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution: Set `devenv.exe` to "Run as Administrator" under Properties and Compatibility tab.  Voila!